# What is wrong with my Haskell definition of the bind operator in this example?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc, ghci

I'm following a monad transformers tutorial [here](https://github.com/kqr/gists/blob/master/articles/gentle-introduction-monad-transformers.md).

[At this point in the tutorial](https://github.com/kqr/gists/blob/master/articles/gentle-introduction-monad-transformers.md#implementing-instances-for-common-typeclasses), it asks me to try to implement the Monad instance for the `EitherIO` data type, defined as:

```
data EitherIO e a = EitherIO {
    runEitherIO :: IO (Either e a)
}
```

So I tried:

```
instance Functor (EitherIO e) where
  fmap f = EitherIO . fmap (fmap f) . runEitherIO

instance Monad (EitherIO e) where
  return  = EitherIO . return . Right
  x >>= f = join $ fmap f x
```

The tutorial's version was a bit different:

```
instance Monad (EitherIO e) where
  return  = pure -- the same as EitherIO . return . Right
  x >>= f = EitherIO $ runEitherIO x >>= either (return . Left) (runEitherIO . f)
```

Now, the types all fit, so I thought I was good, and congratulated myself on finally finding a use for [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join).

As it turns out, [further down the tutorial](https://github.com/kqr/gists/blob/master/articles/gentle-introduction-monad-transformers.md#do-you-even-lift), I was asked to run `runEitherIO getToken` on the following:

```
liftEither x = EitherIO (return x)
liftIO x = EitherIO (fmap Right x)

getToken = do
  liftIO (T.putStrLn "Enter email address:")
  input <- liftIO T.getLine
  liftEither (getDomain input)
```

Using my version of the `>>=` operator, GHCi would hang after I provided some input. Then even after I interrupt via `^C`, GHCi would start acting strangely, hanging for a second or two while I'm typing. I'd have to kill GHCi to restart. When I replaced the `>>=` definition with the tutorial definition, everything worked.

My full file is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2daef0e73aa627725197).

So:

1. What is wrong with my definition?
2. Why would GHCi typecheck and then behave like it did? Is this a GHCi bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that this is the culprit:

```
instance Monad (EitherIO e) where
  return  = EitherIO . return . Right
  x >>= f = join $ fmap f x
```

However, `join` is defined as:

```
join x = x >>= id
```

However, in this way `join` and `>>=` get defined in a mutually recursive way which leads to non termination.

Note that this type checks, much as the following does:

```
f, g :: Int -> Int
f x = g x
g x = f x
```

Bottom line: you should provide a definition for `>>=` which does not involve `join`.

Comment: You actually *cannot* define `join`, it is not a method of the class. There were plans to make it one in the AMP proposal, but it stranded on a bad interaction with the role system for newtype deriving. (Basically it would have made newtype deriving for monad stacks impossible.)

Comment: I see ... I don't suppose there is a list of functions available that is tagged as off-limits for use in Monad definitions?

Comment: @Ana There is none, AFAIK. The thumb rule is that you should not use any function requiring `Monad (EitherIO e)` to define the instance itself. (This circular definition might still lead to termination in some cases, but more often than not is does not.)

Answer (score 5):

[`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) in `Control.Monad` is defined as follows:

```
join              :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
join x            =  x >>= id
```

You see, that `join` is defined in terms of `>>=`. So the short answer is, that your definition of `>>=` gets into an endless loop (i.e. does not terminate), because it uses `join`, which in turn uses `>>=` again.

If you think about it, you could use this definition of `>>=` for every `Monad`. So it cannot possibly work, because it makes no use of the internal structure of the type at all.

As for why this is not detected by `ghc`, this is an endless loop, but not a type error. The type system of Haskell is not powerful enough to detect such loops.